# Can't submit form using CKEditor?

Tags: forms, symfony, ckeditor, submit-button

I have the following form:

```
<form action="/web/app_dev.php/system/blog/new" method="post" >
    <div id="newblogpost">
    <div>
        <label for="newblogpost_title" class="required">Title</label>
        <input type="text" id="newblogpost_title" name="newblogpost[title]" required="required" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="newblogpost_status">Status</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="newblogpost_status" name="newblogpost[status]" value="1" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="newblogpost_content" class="required">Content</label>
        <textarea id="newblogpost_content" name="newblogpost[content]" required="required"    class="ckeditor" id="editor1"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="newblogpost__token" name="newblogpost[_token]" value="f58cad16c1948231a504f592ec74edd7aaeca29d" /></div>

    <button type="submit">Cmon?</button>
</form>
```

For some reason, I can't get the damn thing to submit. If I disable CKEditor on my textarea field, it will submit, which (obviously) leads me to believe it's an issue with CKEditor.

I've tried a few things like various names for field inputs, an input type="submit" rather than a button, etc with no luck.

I can't seem to find anyone else having the same issue, all I end up finding is people having issues with AJAX forms. This is just a straight-forward, old-fashioned submit-able form.

Am I missing something semantic preventing this from submitting? Or can anyone else spot an issue?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't submit ? Do you get an error ? Cause there's no way this form won't submit as this is basic HTML

Comment: No errors, nothing in firebug console, nothing in Chrome or IE's developer console. It's been driving me crazy! All I can assume is that CKEditor is preventing the default action of the submit buttons... but how? and Why? :S

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You apparently have the problem on all browsers, and the article is quite old, but [this post](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Chrome-specific-HTML5-specific-bug) seems to indicate that the "required" attribute may be the source. Can you check without this attribute ?

Comment: Thank you so much for that, I've spent an afternoon tearing my hair out over this one. Much appreciated. (The daft thing is, this did occur to me and I set my BlogPost entity (Symfony/Doctrine) to be nullable, assuming it would exclude the required attribute as is the case with text fields but never checked - doh!).

Comment: I've got a good news - patch for https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/8031 will perhaps land in the next minor release (4.1.1) planned in 2 weeks. Although it may be delayed if we won't find a fix in reasonable time.

Comment: This is still an issue in ckeditor5 v37.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is still active with  `https://cdn.ckeditor.com/#ckeditor5`

As mentioned it can be fixed by bypassing html5 validation.
i.e.
`<button type="submit" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" >Submit Data</button>`